# Call a Grails restful web service in a spring security application

Tags: grails, spring-security

I need to submit a simple and unique request to a web service hosted inside a regular web based Grails application which is secured with Spring Security plugin. My request should look like:

```
curl -F username=john password=mypass message="Hello World" http://localhost:8080/myapp/restapi/echo
```

No work flow, just an unique request and I'm done.

I have a simple secured controller to respond to this request as follows:

```
@Secured(["ROLE_REST_CLIENT"])
class RestapiController {
  def echo() {
    respond params.message
  }
}
```

The issue here is that spring security default behavior is to redirect any new request to the login page. How can I change that, search the http params for the user name and password, register the user and go on TO the requested controller action, all in the same unique stateless request?

I had a look at [Spring Security REST Plugin](https://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-rest) but it is aimed to provide a token-based work flow which isn't exactly what I need. (I would also appreciate some guidance to this work flow approach as an optional solution)

Comment: I'm sure you don't want to hear this but I'd strongly advice to reconsider sending credential as request params especially over insecure HTTP connection. As an alternative, you can allow all access on that resource (i.e. exclude this uri from SpringSecurity) and implement security within the REST controller.

Comment: Can you try adding below code in config.groovy
`grails.plugin.springsecurity.interceptUrlMap = [
  '/restapi/**':         ['IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY']]` this will allow you to access your action without login

Comment: Thanks @defectus. Which option do I have not to expose my credentials as request params?

Comment: Token based authentication is a good pick. You don't have to use Spring Security REST, however it is the most widely used one. Other option is to use HTTP Basic authentication (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication)